# starting a python 3.3. script at ubuntu startup

Tags: python, ubuntu

The standard python version of ubuntu 13.04 is python 2.7.
I know that I can call a python script of version 3.3 by calling python3.3 or python3 in terminal instead of only "python", which starts the version 2.7...

e.g. python3 myscript.py

But now I have a version 3.3. script in the system start routine and can only tell the path to the file. The system recognizes it as a python script (in the shebang with #!/usr/bin/python3)
But how to open it with the correct version? It is tried to be opened with the standard python install so it wont work nor even show up.

Comment: The `#!/usr/bin/python3` should do the trick, I think. Have you tried running a script that only prints the Python version, and redirecting the output to a file (so you can check it after it finishes)?

Comment: I havent tried printing yet, good idea

Comment: This question has already been asked. Take a look at


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718821/run-python-script-as-daemon-at-boot-time-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shebang line `#!/usr/bin/python3` should work if sh, bash, etc. is trying to launch your script.

It it is being run from another script as `python myscript.py` you'll have to find that script and get it to launch the script using `python3 myscripy.py`

Comment: Hm I dont understand, I also think it should work.
E.g. there is a programm that is called with
"/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-stickynotes/indicator-stickynotes.py", the file is owned by root.
my file is placed in /home, owned by me and called the same way, both have the same shebangs (python3). But my file does not open

Comment: I changed the call in the system startup routine to "python3 /home/me/abcdcasdf.py and now it works. strange that it only worked on the second reboot, but ok.